# Decode unicode escape sequences in JavaScriopt string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like `\uC88B\uC544\uC694`.

In a node repl (v7.4.0), this statement shows '좋아요' correctly,
but in the below code, it's not working.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
  {
    url: 'http://book.daum.net/dwr/call/plaincall/ajaxDetailController.getReviewListByPageNo.dwr',
    form: {
      callCount: 1,
      'c0-id': 0,
      'c0-scriptName': 'ajaxDetailController',
      'c0-methodName': 'getReviewListByPageNo',
      'scriptSessionId': '${scriptSessionId}714',
      'batchId': 6,
      'c0-param0': 'Object_Object:{bookid: KOR9791186757093, pageNo: 1, pageSize: 6}'
  }
}, 
(error, response, body) => {
  var str = 's2';
  var regex = new RegExp(str + `.\\w*\\=[\\"\\w\\d\\s\\\\\\&\\:\\/\\.]*\\;`, 'g');
  const arr= body.match(regex);
  /* HERE */
  console.log(arr[14].split('"')[1]);
  console.log(arr[25].split('"')[1]);
  console.log(arr[41].split('"')[1]);
  console.log(arr[35].split('"')[1]);
  console.log(arr[44].split('"')[1]);
  console.log(arr[13].split('"')[1]);
}
);
```

Why it doesn't show the correct string?

Comment: We don't know what your post request returns, which makes it difficult for us to help you. Please post some example data and a snippet we can run that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @gyre That's it. What request returns is book information of [here](http://book.daum.net/detail/book.do?bookid=KOR9791186757093). The web sends the request using javascript. so I want to scrap the page using ajax behind javascript code.

Comment: The request returns information of the book correctly, and arr[14],arr[25]..etc. includes a replier, name, etc.. but `console.log` shows raw data like `\uC88B\uC544\uC694`

Comment: What's important is the information in the response headers.

Comment: @Pointy more detail answer please.

Comment: @dalihigh more detail **question** please. Your problem may have to do with character encoding, so without seeing the HTTP response headers it's hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: Content-Type →text/javascript, Date →Sat, 18 Mar 2017 20:46:54 GMT, Server →Apache, Transfer-Encoding →chunked. That's all i can see in postman.

Comment: Have you tried adding the following attribute in your form declaration: '"accept-charse":"UTF-8"' - it could make the server see the Unicode properly - if that is your problem.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff it's solved, thanks. `accept-charset` header requires postman interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `JSON.parse` to escape your string data.

Not knowing the structure of your POST response, I'm sure there is a more elegant solution to this problem but this is the best I can do with the information you've provided. Hope this helps.

```js
(error, response, body) => {
  var str = 's2';
  var regex = new RegExp(str + `.\\w*\\=[\\"\\w\\d\\s\\\\\\&\\:\\/\\.]*\\;`, 'g');
  const arr = body.match(regex);
  /* HERE */
  var data = [ arr[14], arr[25], arr[41], arr[35], arr[44], arr[13] ]
    .map(function (e) { return e.split('"')[1] })
    
  data = JSON.parse('["' + data.join('","') + '"]')
  
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: `\uHHHH` (where `H` is a hexademical digit) is an escape sequence used to encode unicode characters in JavaScript and JSON. You can unescape these sequences by treating them as JSON strings and then calling `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I've tested it in node repl, it's working. but stdout shows the '\u1234' not '\\u1234'. why stdout shows one '\' ?

Comment: `console.log('\uC88B\uC544\uC694');` shows `좋아요`. and `console.log('\\uC88B\\uC544\\uC694');` shows `\\uC88B\\uC544\\uC694`

Comment: yes, i can parse expression using `JSON.parse('["' + '\\uC88B\\uC544\\uC694' + '"]')`. but what request returns was form of `'\uC88B\uC544\uC694'`. Why does this happen?

Comment: The backslash is the escape character in javascript strings, so to get a literal backslash you have to write `'\\'`.

Comment: If stdout doesn't support all of unicode, it might default to escape sequences. Otherwise I would suggest duplicating the line `data = JSON.parse('["' + data.join('","') + '"]')` to parse the string once more.

Comment: ok, but what request returns was not 2 backslash.. In node repl, `'\\uC88B\\uC544\\uC694'` returns '\\uC88B\\uC544\\uC694', and `\uC88B\uC544\uC694` returns `좋아요`.

Comment: Aha!!, you are right. `>If stdout doesn't support all of unicode, it might default to escape sequences.`. thanks. you're genious!!!

Comment: Can it is applied to any expression to decode?(includes any special character).

Comment: I changed the expression to const regex = new RegExp(`(${item}.((content)|(cpName)|(registryDatetime)|(sourceURL)|(title)|(name)){1}=").+?(";)`, 'g'); Here, ${item} is one of s2 or s3, s4, s5, s6, s7.